# How to force css calc output in pixels in old browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

For some reasons, my application have to support Chrome 23+. With the following CSS:

```
.third-floor {
  top: -webkit-calc(100% * 0.16 * 2);
  top: calc(100% * 0.16 * 2);
}
```

I have the following computed values:

- **Chrome 59**: 183.984px
- **Chrome 23**: 32%

A percentage value breaks the layout. I need it in pixels. I have tried:

```
.third-floor {
  top: -webkit-calc(100% * 0.16 * 2 + 1px);
  top: calc(100% * 0.16 * 2);
}
```

but I get an empty value for the top. Any ideas of how I could force the ouput in pixels?

Comment: Have you tried vh instead of %

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome 23 doesn't support vh

Comment: According to caniuse it's not supporting vmax

Comment: As you can't force CSS Calc to anything other than what it does on a certain build, you need a script. Another options is to better describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My bad, `vh` is actually supported. `top: 10vh` works, but `calc(10vh)` does not

Comment: @LGSon, I was afraid it'd come to that :/